# using old laravel with multiple select javascript

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

im has succeeded with single input use `old` in laravel and return my old input when im wrong input or null the form here the code

```html
<select name="member_id" class ="form-control">
      <option selected="true" disabled="true">Select Member Name</option>
      @foreach($members as $member => $m)        
      <option value="{{$m->id}}" {{(old("member_id") == $m->id ? "selected":"")}}>
      {{$m->member_no}} - {{$m->member_name}}</option>
      @endforeach
 </select>
```

but when i use mutiple input javascript and its nothing happened
here the code

```js
function AddBorrowing()
        {
            var row = '<tr>'+
            '<td>'+
            '<select name="book_id[]">'+
            '<option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select Book</option>'+
            '@foreach($books as $book => $b)' +       
            '<option value="{{in_array($b->id, old("book_id") ?: []) ? "selected": ""}}">{{$b->book_title}}</option>'+
            '@endforeach </select>'+
            '</select>'+
            '</td>'+
'</tr>';

            $("#tbody").append(row);
               
        };
        function deleteRow(btn)
        {
            var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        };
        AddBorrowing(); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/X73vB/) add your data first into an `array` and then assign a value to `selectbox`